# Is it mandatory to initialize class members if a constructor is explicitly defined?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, class-members

My college course book states that :

> When a constructor is declared for a class, initialization of the class objects becomes mandatory.

Link to the [specific page of the book.](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=TN9wQjjDwp0C&lpg=PP1&ots=kD54R42bUr&dq=object%20oriented%20programming%20in%20c%2B%2B&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q&f=false)

We can declare do-nothing constructors and hence initialization is most certainly not mandatory, or is it?

If not, does the author mean that *stylistically* we should initialize class members if we explicitly declare constructors, that is, is it meant as a rule or a guideline?

Comment: side note : throw out that book and get some good one specified by SO, I've seen it before. Filled with crap practice, crap theory ....

Comment: Agreed with Mr. Anubis. I have only read that page and I am already confused with the terminology...

Comment: I am almost done with it. I agree with you on that. It skims over just about everything that actually needs a little thinking or depth. There arent any books recommended by SO explicitly for OOP with C++ [basic to intermediate], though. @Mr.Anubis

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When a constructor is declared for a class, initialization of the class objects becomes mandatory.

It's true, but initialization doesn't have to be explicit. Note the term `objects` instead of `member`.

Class-type members will be default-intialized if you don't explicitly do it.

```
class A {};
class B
{
   A a;
   int x;
   B()
   {
      //a is initialized here, although you didn't do it explicitly

      //x is not initialized, nor is it mandatory to initialize it
      //but x is not an object
   }
};
```

Of course, "mandatory" is a strong word. It's not mandatory to initialize `x`, but you can't do anything with it until you do. :)

Comment: 1. I dont think he is referring to class objects which are class members, but POD variables. But i see your point. 
2. Exactly my problem with this statement, "mandatory" ...

Comment: @AshRj that's why I specified "class-type", in case this isn't what he meant.

Answer (score 7):

We must initialize members in constructor if:

1. Member has no default constructor.
2. Member is reference/const-reference.
3. Member is const. (Thanks to Mr.Anubis)

And should initialize members if we dont't want any strange behaviour if:

1. Member is pointer
2. Member is standard pod-type

Comment: just to complete your list , one must initialize if member is const also